# MS Access SQL Update Query using Inner Joins

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-update, inner-join

I have been trying to get a query working with MS Access. I am using C#.NET oledb to access the database. I have successfully accessed the database with SELECT, DELETE and simpler UPDATE queries. This UPDATE is a little more complex-- tying together three tables with INNER JOINS. I have INNER JOINed three tables several times with SELECT. No problem with that. This one keeps giving me the error "No value given for one or more required parameters." There are only four parameters. I found that one of them was a 16 bit integer, so I changed it to a Short before using it. All the values are there. All the tables and columns are there and are spelled correctly. I am showing the ? syntax, but I also used the other syntax of giving a variable name in the SQL starting with "@", like "@index"; That is the syntax I usually use everywhere else, but it did not work here. The parameters are listed in the same order that they are found in the SQL. That has given me trouble before also. So I am wondering if anyone has other ideas of what could be wrong with this query.

```
string sConn = dataBaseClass.getAccessDBsymbolLibConnString(sSEPfilename);
Int16 nCoreIndexShort = (short)nCoreIndex;
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(sConn))
{
    using (OleDbCommand addCommand = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        string sSQL = "UPDATE ([ConnectionTarget] AS C  INNER JOIN [Connection] AS B ON C.[Connection] = B.[Counter]) ";
        sSQL += "INNER JOIN [Component] AS A ON B.[CompCounter] = A.[Counter] ";
        sSQL += "SET C.[WireColor] = ?, C.[WireSize] = ? ";
        sSQL += "WHERE A.[Counter] = ? AND B.[ConnectionNumber] = ?; ";
        addCommand.CommandText = sSQL;
        addCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("C.[WireColor]", sColor);
        addCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("C.[WireSize]", sSize);
        addCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("A.[Counter]", nMulticoreFanout);
        addCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("B.[ConnectionNumber]", nCoreIndexShort);
        addCommand.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        int nDone = addCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help. No, MS Access is not my preferred database to interact with, but I have no choice here.

Comment: This means you have not supplied a value. Check using breakpoint if there is a null object ref. Also change the parameters from table.column to ? and supply the values in order of input

Comment: Try to run your query directly in MS-Access. If there is an error it con pinpoint the problem better.